# Объединить одинаковые элементы массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет,сразу говорю не очень силен в php, уже который раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой.

Есть двумерный массив данных, в данном массиве есть значения которые повторяются "не случайно", мне не нужно их убрать или удалить повторяющиеся, мне нужно наоборот чтобы получился еще один массив но только с повторяющимися элементами. Т.е. объединить повторяющиеся элементы массива в другой массив. Не могу понять как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Если повторяются значения, можно использовать [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect.php), если ключи - [`array_intersect_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect-assoc.php).

Пример для `array_intersect()`:

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);

// Array
// (
//     [a] => green
//     [0] => red
// )
```

Пример для `array_intersect_assoc()`:

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "yellow", "blue", "red");
$result_array = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
print_r($result_array);

// Array
// (
//     [a] => green
// )
```

Comment: Не совсем то, дело в том, что элементы повторяются в одном и том же массиве, поле sort к примеру

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно, что является признаком уникальности элемента. В моём примере это свойство объекта `id`

```
$source = []; // исходный массив
$unique = []; // массив для определения уникальности элемента
$doubles = []; // только дубли

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value->id, $unique)) {
        $doubles[] = $value;
        unset($array[$key]);
    } else {
        $unique[] = $value->id;
    }
}

// в итоге в $source остануться только уникальные значения
// в $doubles - только дубли
```